# Object.getClass().getSuperclass() not returning null?

Tags: java, oop, superclass

I have a function

```
public void get(Object s) {

  while (s.getClass().getSuperclass() != null) {
      s = s.getClass().getSuperclass();
  }
}
```

The thing is that the `s.getClass().getSuperclass()` never returns `null`, even though `Object` has no superclass.

I don't understand why this is happening, although I debugged the project several times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you assign a Class to `s`:

```
s = s.getClass().getSuperclass();
```

Then the loop condition is:

```
s.getClass().getSuperclass();
```

A Class object's class is `Class.class` whose `getSuperclass` returns `Object.class` so the loop condition evaluates to true.

Then you assign `s` to `Object.class`:

```
s = s.getClass().getSuperclass();
```

Whose class is `Class.class` and has a super class. Repeat ad infinitum.

Use a different variable for the class.

```
Class<?> cls = s.getClass().getSuperclass();
while(cls != null) {
    cls = cls.getSuperclass();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

After the first time you run your loop, `s` is a `Class` instance.

`s.getClass()` therefore always returns `Class.class`, which has a superclass.

Comment: Thanks. I do not understand how to solve my problem though. How do I make it return null once it no longer has a superclass? How do I modify my code to achieve that?

Comment: In other words, only do the getClass() the first time.

Comment: @Gregg1989 - Not if you did it right.  Use getClass() outside the loop, once, to get the class of the input parm.  Then never use it again.

Comment: Oh, I see now, I used getClass() on the first line of the while loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

**[Why your code won't work was explained by SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22047114/2316112)**

What you want is this:

```
public void get(Object s)
{
    Class<?> buffer = s.getClass();

    while (buffer != null)
    {
        System.out.println(buffer);
        buffer = buffer.getSuperclass();

    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate it Phillipp. Rep'd